# how to get bounding box, and bottom bounding box for an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

For an image, I calculated all the bounding boxes. I wanted to remove the bounding boxes which comes at the bottom of the image, since they are not my ROI.

can some one help to remove the bottom portion from the image using the calculated bounding box.

Comment: Please give more information about your bounding boxes. E.g. Are those boxes defined by two pairs of matrix entries and also, if you remove them, with what value do you want to overwrite them?

Comment: Hi Pablo, I used  the following code to get the bounding boxes. Image3 is a black and image. After finding the bounding box from bottom , I need to fill that areas in black colour.                                                                                                                                                                      
                [labeledImage, numberOfBlobs] = bwlabel(Image3);
measurements = regionprops(labeledImage, 'BoundingBox');

Comment: Ok and what do you want to substitute them with?

Comment: pixels in to black .

Comment: How do you define the bottom bounding boxes? What is the difference between those you want to remove and those you would like to keep? If location is always the same you could always fill e.g. rows 200 - max(row) with black. `labeledImage(200:end,:) = 0`

Comment: kkuilla many thanks! This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a monochromatic image (black and white) called `Image3`. As you already said, you are calculating a bounding box around your "distorsions".

```
[labeledImage, numberOfBlobs] = bwlabel(Image3);
measurements = regionprops(labeledImage, 'BoundingBox');
```

By calculating the bounding box `regionprops` you are obviously calculating the position of your distortions, but this is from my point of view redundant probably redundant. Your could simply write:

```
[labeledImage, numberOfBlobs] = bwlabel(Image3);
[x,y]=size(labeledImage);

height_from_top = 0.8;
width_from_left = 1.0;
endIdx_y = round(y*height_from_top);
endIdx_x = round(x*width_from_left);
labeledImage(1:endIdx_x ,1:endIdx_y)=0;

Image3(labeledImage>0)=0; % or 1, depending on the colour...
```

It is very likely that my indices do not exactly match. Unaffortunately I cannot check it right now, but this modification should exclude your lower and most right border depending on what percentage of the image you want to filter in each direction. E.g. setting `height_from_top` to `0.5` should only remove the lower half of your image.

Comment: Pablo, Image3(labeledImage>0)=0; gives me a full black image, I need to find the bottom most bounding boxes and refill all that bottom areas with black pixels, preserving all other text area in the image.